# Blazor validation with generated Entity Framework models

Tags: .net, entity-framework, validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor Server and my model classes are generated using the EF Core Power Tools, and I'm using a database-first approach. We are moving from ASP.NET MVC and I need to work out how we are going to implement validation of our model classes.

With ASP.NET MVC we would create a base service with this:

```
public interface IValidationDictionary
{
    void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
    bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

Each service that inherited from the base service would create a `Validate` method like this:

```
    public override bool Validate(object entity)
    {
        if (entity is UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userProfile.description))
            {
                _ValidationDictionary.AddError("description", "Please provide a profile name");
            }
        }
    }
```

The controllers would create each service with a wrapper that would add a collection of `ModelStateDictionary` errors based on any test that failed and added to `_ValidationDictionary`.

This approach worked perfectly as we could apply extremely complex validation checks (including ones that might need to talk to the database) and bind the result to the Model with custom messages which we could then display using the `ValidationmessageFor` helper. The great thing here was that we could build all of these tests without them needing to be bound directly to the model class (as the model classes get overwritten each time we refresh the context using EF Power Tools).

Obviously with Blazor this approach will not necessarily work. Can anyone offer any advice on how I might best structure validation with Blazor?

Comment: Check out [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html) and [Blazored.FluentValidation](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation). It's super easy to write complex validation logic and wiring that up to the UI is pretty straightforward.

Comment: this has absolutely done the trick - thank you